# Does my IOS app contain encryption

Tags: ios, encryption

I going to be submitting an app to the IOS App Store soon and I'm wondering if my app contains encryption? I used a `[[UIApplication sharedApplication openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]]`. That code does go out to a secure payment site. Does my app contain encryption?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about contracts with Apple and AppStore rules.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**, it doens't.

With that code you are just going out of the app opening a link.
So, it doesn't touch your app.